# Error with passing function from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, pointers

The error I got:

> [Warning] passing arg 1 of `(my function)' from incompatible pointer type

I tried to get my function to read 3 things. I already declared my void function. I already created `char* board`, `char* vehicle`, `char* distance` in my function.

it is in int main()

```
moveCar(&board, &vehicle, &distance);
```

it doesn't run my program correctly. What can I do to make it to work smooth?

Updated:

since some of you guys want to take a look at my function. here it is.

```
void moveCar(char* board[], char* vehicle, char* direction)
{
     int i;
     for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
         if(board[i] = vehicle)
         {
                     if(*direction = 'r')
                     {
                          if(*board[i + 1] = '.')
                          {
                                swap(board, (&i), (&i + 1));
                          }
                     }
                     else if (*direction = 'l')
                     {
                          if(*board[i - 1] = '.')
                          {
                                swap(board, (&i), (&i - 1));
                          }
                     }
                     else if (*direction = 'd')
                     {
                          if(*board[i + 8] = '.')
                          {
                                swap(board, (&i), (&i + 8));
                          }
                     }
                     else if(*direction = 'u')
                     {
                          if(*board[i - 8] = '.')
                          {
                                swap(board, (&i), (&i - 8));
                          }
                     }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: we should at least see the function declaration and the arguments declaration

Comment: show more code: ideally, both your function definition and the place from where it's called.

Comment: Unless `my_function` is actually a function pointer (and I'm guessing it isn't), it should not be in brackets.

Comment: Are you sure you want to pass the address of `board` etc.? If they're strings, you leave off the `&`

Comment: Please update your question to include the definition of `my function` (whatever it is).

Comment: @Ashalynd here it is.

Comment: and the calling code? including the variables you use as function arguments.

Answer (score 0):

According to the definitions of your function and variables

```
char* board;
char* vehicle;
char* distance;

void moveCar(char* board[], char* vehicle, char* direction) { ... }
```

You should call `moveCar()` as

```
moveCar(&board, vehicle, distance);
```

Comment: True, but this doesn't explain the `1` in the quoted error message.

Comment: @leeduhem I retyped the moveCar() and the errors I got are:    [Warning] passing arg 1 of `moveCar' from incompatible pointer type [Warning] passing arg 2 of `moveCar' makes pointer from integer  [Warning] passing arg 3 of `moveCar' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: @Cam9191 What is your real definitions of variables `board`, `vehicle`, and `direction`? Please also including these in your question.